# API Key for Google Java Script API

Tags: google-maps

I have read the documentation at the below site. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#get-an-api-key
I would like to use the API key with http referrer restriction in both my salesforce sandboxes(FULL & UAT) and production.
I still have the following questions:
1. Can I add multiple http referrers to the same free API Key?
2. Can I use the free API Key in production? or do I need to get a premium plan?
3. When does the free API key expire?

Thanks
Neema

Answer (score 0):

There are important changes in Google Maps you should be aware of. Starting from June 11, 2018 Google migrates to the Google Maps Platform. It was announced on May 2, 2018, so starting from today there is no anymore Standard plan (free version) and Premium plan in Google Maps. You have unified Google Maps platform for all users with a free $200 per month limit.

I would suggest reading the following document to have an idea about incoming changes:

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/

Now, referring to your questions

- yes, you can use multiple HTTP referrer restrictions on the same API key
- there are no Standard plan API keys anymore, you have only Google Maps Platform API keys with a $200 free limit
- There are no expiration date for API key, but you have to activate billing account in order to use an API key.

I hope my answers clarify your doubts!

Comment: Thank you! From the document I am unable to tell how many map loads are allowed with the free $200? I opened a ticket with google sales to understand further.  Also I am trying to restrict the API key to a http referrer and it does not work. We are on salesforce and I am trying this out in our FULL sandbox which has the my-domain turned on.(Example:https://ebi--full.my.salesforce.com/*). Any idea on this?

Comment: Check error message in browser console when API key with restriction doesn't work. Usually it says which referrer should be enabled. Alternatively check the value of `window.location.href` when you load salesforce page, this is a URL that you should use as a restriction.